# hyperlink text in Outlook mails

Tags: hyperlink, outlook

There is hyperlink text in a outlook mailitem. eg. [Test](http://google.co.in)

could you please let me know on how to find the hyperlink text 'Test' and its URL address from mailitem bodytext.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the hyperlink and click "Copy Hyperlink".  Then paste to your favorite text editor.   This is with Outlook 2007.

Comment: Sorry i missed to mention this - i have to find the hyperlink link along with URL address thru code i.e outlook vba